# How do you cope with a team who tends to underestimate time needed to complete tasks?

Tags: agile, project-management, scrum, estimation

How do you cope with a team who tends to underestimate time needed to complete tasks and haven't been improving the accuracy of their estimates?

Details:
I work in a scrum team (7 engineers) in a FANG company, at the end of every sprint, we vote to estimate how many hours we need to spend on each user story for next sprint. Then we assign these stories to each one of us according to our available capacity.

I've been here for a year and we have a very persistent problem: almost everybody can't finish planned work in almost every sprint. We have huge carryovers in every sprint.

I tend to vote for larger estimates, but my teammates almost never learn from their past mistakes and persistently vote low in these estimations.

I'm the kind of person who just want work for 40 hours/week, chill and avoid burnout. I believe in 'underestimate and over-deliver'. I know some of my teammates work long hours all the time. Our scrum master works extra hours almost everyday yet she still vote very low all the time. She's been around for quite a while so we respect her opinions.

They might each have different incentives, like to impress the management or conform with the others? Maybe they want fast promotion? I don't know and I don't care. I try to cope with it by taking a strong lead in my own project and voice my concerns in planning meetings. But sometimes I get assigned to user stories that are estimated by the team. And they usually have ridiculous expectations, like launching a new small production service from scratch in a week. Remember it's a big company which has a lot of internal processes, and a teammate have told me it takes at least 3 weeks to launch a bare born service. I was on vacation when this estimation happened.

Also I would look bad if I have big carryover points too often.

My manager is kind of a people pleaser and tend to accept ridiculous deadlines from other team or upper management. Thankfully my manager listens to me.

Sorry for the long rant. I actually like my team and manager, so I don't want leave. I know we are doing agile all wrong but they don't change, and don't seem to care about working long hours.

Comment: What *software* problem are you trying to solve here? It seems your problems here are people problems, not software problems.

Comment: I'd say both, I thought about asking on workplace but not everyone there knows how agile works.

Comment: This question should probably be migrated to [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: There's something I don't quite understand about your question... What prevents you from simply slipping work to the next sprint and adjusting your velocity points?  There's a reason they're called sprints; sometimes you don't reach the finish line on time.  If you're up against a hard deadline, you can slip features instead of working late.  Your question suggests only one possible course of action, when there might be others.

Comment: In the absence of detailed specifications (which you generally don't have in an Agile setting) or velocity adjustment, my rule of thumb for estimation is to multiply by 2x to 3x the amount of time you actually *think* it's going to take.

Comment: Also, if your internal processes always take (more or less) the same amount of time, you can simply add those to the end of every estimate.

Comment: I stopped reading when you mentioned using Scrum and then assigning hours to Stories. I personally believe these two concepts are contrary and is why things aren’t working the way you want.

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell: If velocity has been adequately determined, going from points to hours is just a simple conversion factor anyway.

Comment: Estimate in story points - even if inaccurate they are self-balancing as long as your estimates are consistent and you plan based on what was **completed** in previous sprints. The bigger issue is that this has been happening for a year, which means either the team doesn't have effective retrospectives, or the team just believes this is fine / scrum working as intended.

Comment: How big are your stories/estimation-units? The bigger the story the worse the estimation. In my opinion a good story size is when it can be done in one day

Comment: Sidenote: "...in a **FANG** company..." -> I'd say there lies the problem. People probably want to look better and/or superhuman to honor the place of work. That being said, do your 8 hours/day, do your work as seriously as possible. You'll probably won't stay long enough to climb the corporate ladder, but that's not the point. At your dying bed you won't look back and regret that you didn't put long hours as your co-workers did. You'll regret the time you could be spending doing something meaningful. A job is just a job, unless you're either Elon Musk or Jeff Bezos.

Comment: Totally agreed Machado, sometimes I suspect this is the root problem and there's no way for me to change.

Comment: We split stories into small tasks but the estimations are still often unrealistic. As if nobody wants to vote larger than 2 days. I think a lot of the pressure comes from outside (like PM or management already decided a deadline).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Except they are not related in any way. The idea of points and velocity is to discuss complexity. No one is every correct with hours. Writing software is not objectively procedural. It must be fluid. It’s why we are always wrong with estimates. And if someone is correct then they wasted time or took shortcuts to hit the “guess.”

Answer (score 3):

You do have sprint retrospectives, right? That is the time to question: "How do we explain we did not burn down much? Again?" There may be excuses that won't make much sense to you. Just take note. Do this after each sprint. A time will come at which no one can argue any longer with the explanation you regard as obvious.

In any planning session you could ask "What is different now, what makes us believe this time we will meet this low estimate? Or do we not really believe it ourselves? Whom do we think we are kidding this time?" You are going to be real popular .

On the practical side, others may just not foresee the things they may or most surely will have to deal with. You may be able to point out these things.

> Then we assign these stories to each one of us according to our
>   available capacity

This is not very Scrum-like. Team members typically pick and choose their own issues from the set selected for the sprint.

First and foremost, this is the team's problem, not your personal one. The team comes out unreliable every time. So technically it is not a matter of you dealing with the team, you are part of the team. If it doesn't feel that way, perhaps it's not worth your while.

Answer (score 2):

The 'official' answer for aglie development is to estimate in 'points' rather than hours and adjust your expected progress based on the 'velocity' or points achieved in the last sprint.

However. You don't really need to change much. You know how many 'estimated hours' you achieved in the last sprint vs the actual number of person hours there were.

So you know by how much you underestimate. Simply put less hours worth of tasks in the sprint to compensate.

The points approach is designed to de-emphasise estimation, which is never very accurate under the best of conditions, and just get you to achieve the goal of completing what you put in the next sprint. Rather than worrying about how long each task will actually take.

I would also recommend 1 week sprints to improve estimation.

Comment: `The 'official' answer for scrum is to estimate in 'points' rather than hours and adjust your expected progress based on the 'velocity' or points achieved in the last sprint.` **Absolutely incorrect.** Please learn about the [Scrum](https://scrumguides.org/) framework.

Comment: hmmm maybe a little hair splitting. does scrum have no 'official' recommendation for estimation these days?

Comment: @AlanLarimer: A bit of explanation would go a long way here.  Is your problem with the word "official" or with the terms "points" and "velocity?"  Simply saying "you're wrong" achieves nothing.

Comment: no, alan is right, scrum doesnt officially recommend points. I have edited

Comment: i guess the problem is what does 'official' scrum mean these days

Comment: Using hours as a way of tracking velocity defeats the entire purpose of Scrum IMHO. While it doesn’t mention points it does mention an abstract system that is RELATIVE to itself. I have never seen a Scrum implementation that uses Hours be successful. Ever.

Comment: what I mean is 'estimated hours', where you accept the estimation is wrong are effectively points. after all, if you do points and assign x to a week sprint then you have said 1 hour is y points. Theres no need to convince everyone to switch to points just to say 'we under estimated by 20% last sprint, maybe lets attempt 20% less this sprint'

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I did provide a link to the "official" source. `i guess the problem is what does 'official' scrum mean these days` The way it has been authoritatively defined and evolved by its creators since its beginnings in the early 1990s, its introduction at OOPSLA in 1995, and in [The Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/) since circa [2009](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1alBmXO9bwvOrnEmLntj02sU39GVGjhjx).

Comment: @AlanLarimer: Sorry, but I'm not going to read that entire website to try and figure out what you were talking about in your original comment, and neither is anyone else.  You can't be bothered to back up your assertion with the most basic of explanations?

Comment: I did, dismayed how wishy washy scrum has become. :(

Comment: The Scrum Guide is ~17 printed pages. `Velocity` was removed completely in 2011; `User Story` was a technique mentioned in 2009 but never a part of the framework; `Burn down` was removed in 2011.

Comment: Over the years Scrum has become more of a framework than a prescriptive process which empowers teams to use the various techniques needed based on their specific context. Most traditional, Taylor-type managers find this challenging due to the lack of a highly constrained, step-by-step set of instructions to follow and many CSMs often know only the specific approach they were taught.

Comment: sure, but mountain goat still push poker planning and jira has burn down graphs in its scrum template. Is the 'scrum guide' still a definitive version of scrum?

Comment: Yes. The Scrum Guide is the definitive version. Scrum co-author Ken Schwaber helped found Scrum Alliance, then left due to issue with their training to form Scrum.org.([1](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/23780/20712)) Many tools and *resources*, such as Mike Cohn's MGS, are often still rooted in traditional project management that have not evolved. Just because some popular *experts* or tools do not follow the official system does not make them correct.

Comment: neither does being the original author. What does hirotaka takeuchi say about burn downs?

Comment: for example heres a whole article about estimates and burn downs from scrum.org https://www.scrum.org/resources/blog/faking-it-estimates-and-metrics-scrum is that official?

Comment: Your argument regarding authors is akin to saying that Microsoft can't tell you what the .NET framework is or isn't. The paper by Takeuchi and Ikujiro was a basis for Scrum, but also isn't the definition. The linked article is not a definition of the framework, but a commentary about how tools that are often used within Scrum, such as burndown charts, are often misunderstood and misused.

Comment: and yours is equivalent to 'tolkien invented orks, so all other fiction with 'orks' in is irrelevant to a diacussion about orks'  regardless of popularity. Technically correct, but blind to reality.

Comment: Strawman. Anyone can discuss the reality of various techniques used within the Scrum framework; that's not being contested. The issue is claiming that the document by the creators is not official and that other's implementations are definitive. There are several aspects of the framework which I dislike, but I still recognize and acknowledge what is actually Scrum.

Comment: I think the issue is that 'the scrum guide' is not all they would teach you on an 'official' scrum course. Its just the bit they give away for free

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why you track [Hours Velocity](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2007/10/26/evidence-based-scheduling/).

Hours Velocity is

```
 estimated hours of completed tasks in sprint   
-----------------------------------------------  
actual hours spent on completed tasks in sprint
```

Oh sure some just add up the story points completed but that is a different metric. Neither are [officially part of scrum anyway](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html). Done this way you can focus on comparing estimations sprint to sprint. Otherwise you get distracted by time not spent on tasks, which is not constant.

Hours Velocity is a measure of how well your team estimates work. Programmers are notoriously optimistic. It's not uncommon for a new team to be off by as much as 1/3rd, that is, need 3 times what they estimated. By tracking and reporting this metric the team learns to adjust it's estimations and improve them over time. This leads to fewer features needing to be dropped mid sprint.

BTW, unless your scrum master is also a developer she shouldn't be voting on estimates or points.

As for taking on work other people has estimated... Screw it. As soon as you get assigned work, come up with your own estimate. If it differs, report it now. Don't whine if you grind away without saying anything and then run outta time. If it's going to be longer than a sprint figure out how to break it up into a smaller task now. Always have something presentable done at end of sprint.

I also recommend 1 week sprints. But that's mostly because it ensures you can't spend much time lost in the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this persistent behaviour also a sign of the software being much too hard to maintain with respect to professional standards. The general feeling is, that things should go faster.

Besides all procedural techniques, like discussing difference in opinion on scrum points, there are some possible issues here:

- The different aspects of the problem are *not elaborated enough in detail*; or peer discussed. Better peer programming, written designs and such might help - if feasible.
- The software system contains *technical debts*: refactoring is needed. When there is too much parallel inheritance, business data and logic is interspersed with taking care of visual components. Hence changes come hard.
- The software system contains *technical debts*: the code relates to undocumented business behaviour. Regression errors happen. Then business code must be totally integrated with documentation on business requirements.
  That documentation must be in readable business language and the code must refer to the documentation and comment the code design.

In general it is hard to reform an existing organisation, without large consensus or organisational power.

But you may add your own measures, like written designs, peer communication, and especially evaluation of past work in technical detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think that before you can figure out what to do about the situation, you need to determine *why* it's happening. Is the problem really that the programmers are terrible at estimating? (It's certainly plausible. Estimates are hard.) Or is the problem that the tasks are underspecified or poorly specified? Or is there some other problem such as constant interruptions, or tasks not on the schedule that need to be addressed immediately?

Once you know why, then you can think about the what of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like part of the problem is that your team thinks that points and stories belong to individuals. I say that because you said:

> Then we assign these stories to each one of us according to our available capacity.

and

> I would look bad if I have big carryover points too often.

Stories and points belong to the team, not the individual.

In Scrum, *you* don't have carryover points, the *team* does. Also, you shouldn't be assigning stories to individuals. At least, you shouldn't be assigning all stories. You decide which stories to work on first, but you only pick stories that you are certain can be completed. Only when those are completed should you pick up the next story in the sprint backlog.

I would suggest that you stop thinking in terms of individual contributors and start thinking in terms of the team as a whole. If a story is started but not completed, *it is the fault of the entire team*. If an individual is in danger of not finishing a story, the rest of the team needs to pitch in to help.

At its core, scrum is very simple. Do a sprint, and figure out how many story points you *completed*. That's how many points you pull into the next sprint. You don't need to vote, you pick that number or you pick fewer. It's just that simple. The next sprint, figure out the average of the previous two and adjust accordingly. Eventually your team will settle on a number, and you'll always pull in that many points.